# Appending options in select box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Current Code: I am using click event to append options to select box.

Issue: It's adding as object.

Help to resolve the issue. I have given below code:

```js
var selectValues = [{
  "cat": "test 1",
  "name": "ram"
}, {
  "cat": "test 2",
  "name": "mothukuri"
}];

$(".appendoptions").click(function() {
  $.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
    $('.supervisoronly')
      .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", key)
        .text(value));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="appendoptions"> Add </button>
<select class="form-control supervisoronly" ></select>
```

Comment: When i open the fiddle, it says content was blocked

Comment: try with `value["cat"]`

Comment: @Carsten: sorry i have given deleted url, check now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```js
var selectValues = [{
  "cat": "test 1",
  "name": "ram"
}, {
  "cat": "test 2",
  "name": "mothukuri"
}];

$(".appendoptions").click(function() {
  alert("alert");
  $.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
    $('.supervisoronly')
      .append($('<option></option>').val(key).text(value.name));       
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="appendoptions"> Add </button>
<select class="form-control supervisoronly" ></select>
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
var selectValues = [{
  "cat": "test 1",
  "name": "ram"
}, {
  "cat": "test 2",
  "name": "mothukuri"
}];

$(".appendoptions").click(function() {
  alert("alert");
  $.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
    $('.supervisoronly')
      .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value", value.name)
        .text(value.name));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="appendoptions"> Add </button>
<select class="form-control supervisoronly" ></select>
```

It's because you are getting values as 
`{ "cat": "test 1","name": "ram"}` and `{"cat": "test 1","name": "ram"}`, in iteration, so while making it to string it shows `[object Object]` get `name or cat` value then assign it.

You're trying to get each item's information just like you do with a PHP array. In JavaScript this is an array of objects, and the properties of these objects can be accessed as `object.property`.

Answer (score 2):

You try this code: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmaegsv3/)

```
$('.supervisoronly').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", key).text(value.name));
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
.text(value));
```

should probably be:

```
.text(value.name));
```

(or perhaps `.text(value.cat))` depending on your requirements)

The reason your current code doesn't work is that you are trying to populate each `<option>` with an entire json object, e.g. `{ "cat": "test 1", "name": "ram"}`.

Answer (score 1):

Pure js approach

```js
var selectValues = [{
  "cat": "test 1",
  "name": "ram"
}, {
  "cat": "test 2",
  "name": "mothukuri"
}];

for (var i = 0; i < selectValues.length; i++) {
        var node = document.createElement("option");
        node.value = selectValues[i]["cat"]
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(selectValues[i]["name"]);
        node.appendChild(textnode); 
        document.getElementById("dropdown").appendChild(node); 
    }
```

```html
<select id="dropdown">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var selectValues = [{
        "cat": "test 1",
        "name": "ram"
    }, {
        "cat": "test 2",
        "name": "mothukuri"
    }];

    $(".appendoptions").click(function() {
        var _value = null;
        $.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {
            _value += '<option value="' + key + '">'+ value +'</option>';
            
            $('.supervisoronly').append(_value);
        });
    });
```